# Anyone see how AM-QM inequality is supposed to be used here?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm going through a certain solution, which invokes using AM-QM inequality, but I don't see how.

We are given a sequence $\{a_i\}$ of positive real numbers which for every $k$ satisfy
$$
a_1+\ldots+a_k\geq\frac{k}{a_{k+1}}.
$$
Using which the following is derived
$$
\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}a_ia_j=\sum_{j=2}^n(a_1+\ldots+a_{j-1})a_j\geq \sum_{j=2}^n(j-1)=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}.
$$
Which together with AM-QM inequality is said to imply $a_1+\ldots+a_n\geq n$. I don't see how at all.

AM-QM inequality implies
$$
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2}{n}\geq\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^na_i}{n}\right)^2
$$
or
$$
(n-1)\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2\geq2\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}a_ia_j\geq n(n-1).
$$
Which is equivalent to $\sum_{j=1}^na_i^2\geq n$, not $\sum_{i=1}^na_i\geq n$. So is it a mistake on solver's part or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you know
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2\geq n,\qquad \sum_{i<j}^n a_ia_j\geq\frac{n(n-1)}{2}
$$
which gives
$$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right)^2=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2+2\sum_{i<j}^n a_ia_j\geq n^2
$$
and hence $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\geq n$.